# Render size of an element after changing RowSpan and ColumnSpan

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, size, html-table

I require the size of an element in a `Grid` layout after changing its `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan`. The `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties do not reflect the rendered size.

```xml
<Window x:Class="SizeTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="OnKeyDown">
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Name="testElement" Content="Test" Background="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
</Grid>
```

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var w1 = testElement.ActualWidth;
    var h1 = testElement.ActualHeight;

    Grid.SetColumnSpan(testElement, 2);
    Grid.SetRowSpan(testElement, 2);

    var w2 = testElement.ActualWidth;
    var h2 = testElement.ActualHeight;

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Initial size: {0}x{1}\nNew size: {2}x{3}", w1, h1, w2, h2));
}
```

Output: Initial size: 285.5x160   New size: 285.5x160

Comment: Have you tried `grid.UpdateLayout()` after setting the new Spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will get you the correct result, when the layout of the grid is updated. So you have to get that two properties in the `LayoutUpdated` event of your grid or other parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

After call [Grid.UpdateLayout Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout) `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will reflect the new values.

```
Grid.SetColumnSpan(testElement, 2);
Grid.SetRowSpan(testElement, 2);
grid.UpdateLayout()
```